# Pygame mistake; gradient of the ball

Tags: python, pygame, logic

Long time user, first time asker. Just started using pygame and need some help as right now, my game isn't working as there seems to be a problem with the program choosing a gradient for the ball, and the ball now seems to go in a straight line across the x axis. The code is below, thanks in advance for any help

```
from pygame import *
import time 
import random
init()

width = 1000
height = 1000
screen = display.set_mode((width,height))
display.set_caption('Graphics')

ball1 = Rect(10,10,40,40)
ball1dx = 2
ball1dy = 3

ball2 = Rect(500,500,40,40)

gradient = [-0.25,-0.5,-0.75,-1]
ran = 0

endProgram = False
a = 0
d = 0
w = 0
s = 0

while not endProgram:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == KEYUP:
            if (e.key == K_a):
                a = True
                d = False
                w = False
                s = False
            if (e.key == K_d):
                d = True
                a = False
                w = False
                s = False
            if (e.key == K_w):
                w = True
                a = False
                d = False
                s = False
            if (e.key == K_s):
                s = True
                a = False
                d = False
                w = False
    if a:
        ball2.x -= 1
    if d:
        ball2.x += 1
    if w:
        ball2.y -= 1
    if s:
        ball2.y += 1

ball1.move_ip(ball1dx,ball1dy)
if ball1.y < 0 or ball1.y > height - 40:
    ran = random.random()
    ball1dy *= random.choice(gradient)
if ball1.x < 0 or ball1.x > width - 40:
    ran = random.random()
    ball1dx *= random.choice(gradient)

screen.fill((0,0,200))
draw.ellipse(screen, (0,255,0), ball1)
draw.ellipse(screen, (255,0,0),ball2)
display.update()
```

Comment: Start by fixing your identation.

Comment: I don't know python but it looks to me like you've included a bunch of code that distracts from the problem.  Am I right in thinking that ball1 is the one with the problem and ball2 is entirely irrelevant (as it is keyboard controlled)?  Try stripping the code down to the basics and post it for better answers :)

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Also it doesn't necessarily go along the x axis. It can get stuck going along the y axis also

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you were expecting but if you keep multiplying a number by a fraction between `1` and `0` you will start to approach `0` and essentially get `0`. If you add a print statement after you pick the gradient you will see that your number is quickly heading towards zero.

```
-1.5
-0.5
0.5
-0.375
0.28125
-0.2109375
0.158203125
-0.0791015625
0.059326171875
-0.0296630859375
0.0222473144531
-0.0111236572266
.
.
.
-1.28840161923e-281
6.44200809614e-282
-3.22100404807e-282
3.22100404807e-282
```

I'm assuming you are just trying to get the ball to bounce around screen which you can do by just multiplying by `-1`. If you want variable speed while bouncing you will have to set up a range for min and max speed and only multiply by your gradient if it doesn't exceed those boundaries. You could do it like this

```
ball1.move_ip(ball1dx,ball1dy)
if ball1.y < 0 or ball1.y > height - 40:
    choice = random.choice(gradient)
    if abs(ball1dy*choice) < 5 and abs(ball1dy*choice) > 0.25:
        ball1dy *= choice
    else:
        ball1dy*=-1
if ball1.x < 0 or ball1.x > width - 40:
    choice = random.choice(gradient) 
    if abs(ball1dx*choice) < 5 and abs(ball1dx*choice) > 0.25:
        ball1dx *= choice
    else:
        ball1dx*=-1
```

As a side note you can condense your if statements by changing them all to `False` right before the `if`s and then only switching one to `True` like so

```
for e in event.get():
    if e.type == KEYUP:
        w = False
        a = False
        s = False
        d = False
        if (e.key == K_a):
            a = True
        if (e.key == K_d):
            d = True
        if (e.key == K_w):
            w = True
        if (e.key == K_s):
            s = True
```